# Can't read sessions in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-session

i am struggling with  missing sessions after ajax call. Generally when page is loaded i see in debugbar all sessions:

[image]

Of course I am interested in cartId. If session is present I want to use it to add product to given cart with $cartId. 
Here is simple ajax:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(".buyButton").click(function () {
    addProductToCart($(this).data('id'));
});

function addProductToCart(id_product) {
    var path = 'cart/add-product';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: path,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            id_product: id_product,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('added!');
        },
        error: function (ajaxContext) {
            alert(ajaxContext.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

});

CartController

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public $cartId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        print_r(session::all());
        $this->cartId = $this->getCartId();
        session::put('something',123);
    }
    //REST OF CODE REMOVED 
}
```

I have removed other methods from controller for clarity. Nothing special was there. Basically session::all returns empty array whole time. Additionally I am adding screen from console:
[image]

Routes:

```
Route::group(["namespace" => 'Controllers\FrontEnd', "middleware" => 'web'], function () {
        Route::post('/cart/add-product', 'CartController@addProductToCart');
});
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
             \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageSwitcher::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
];
```

Basically I can't get existing sessions on ajax **but**  when I set new session in ajax called "something" it will exist and persist. I have read many topics about that problem and usually problem was in lack of middleware => web. I have added middleware and cleared all caches with no luck.

Have somebody any ideas how to get sessions in ajax?

Comment: What happens when you use code in `cart/add-product` method instead of constructor?

Comment: I've removed everything from class and used  print_r(session::all()) in addProductToCart and it loaded sessions. Hmm so there must be some problem with constructor somehow. Thanks for idea!

Comment: Since 5.3 session is not explicitly available in constructor. You should retrieve it in method itself. However, there's workaround, check [here](https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/5.3/upgrade.md#session-in-the-constructor).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. I have spend like 2 hours on that problem... now everything is working flawless. Many thanks for help. Have a nice day Tpojka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manipulate sessions in the method *CartController@addProductToCart* and not in the controller constructor. I have a project where I put article in session card with ajax call and it's works fine. Perhaps, it's the solution